# How can we link view to view without the help of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am new to CodeIgniter, and I don't know whether this is possible or not. How can I link view to view without the help of controller just like PHP.

```
{ <a href=''>contact.php</a> }
```

I tried `base_url()`, `site_url()` and `current_url()` but this error displays:

> You don't have permission to access `/Buildon/User/views/contact.php` on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your using codeIgniter site url or base url etc. You should send them to the controller.

**CodeIgniter Doc's** http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

**URI Routing:** http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

**URL Helper:** http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Lets say

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('contact_us');?>">Contact Us</a>
```

The **contact_us** in the base_url would be controller name.

Or Example

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller_name');?>">Example</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/function');?>">Example</a>
```

If you try to send the link to view file will not work.

**Incorrect**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('application/views/example.php');?>">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file in root of this folder parallel to index.php and then you can  access it.